# Running the TWA from a Chromebook just opens the URL in the browser and not a standalone window

Tags: trusted-web-activity, twa

When I download a TWA built like this project (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa) on Chromebooks it only launches the URL inside the Chrome browser and not as a standalone webview. If I install as a PWA then it runs correctly inside a standalone browser. The website is also not cached while running from the TWA unlike the PWA

Has anyone managed to get a TWA running correctly on Chromebooks?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported yet. Support for Trusted Web Activity in Chrome OS is coming in Chrome 86.